# Autofac Singleton and non singleton together

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, autofac

That is my AutoFac setup:

```
  builder.RegisterType<CachingOuterClass>().SingleInstance(); // Singleton
  builder.RegisterType<InnerClassAzureClient>().InstancePerRequest();
```

How can this setup work?

```
public class CachingOuterClass
{
   public CachingOuterClass(InnerClassAzureClient innerClassAzureClient)
  {
      //...
  }
}
```

When the caching outer class is saved forever and once instantiated how can the azure client class be passed by api request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a detailed explanation of this issue in the [FAQ](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/faq/per-request-scope.html). It's too long to put here as an answer.

It does cover your specific question:

> As you analyze the registrations in the problem dependency chain, look
>   at the lifetime scopes for which they’re registered. If you have a
>   component registered as SingleInstance() but it (maybe indirectly)
>   consumes a component registered as InstancePerRequest(), that’s a
>   problem. The SingleInstance() component will grab its dependencies
>   when it’s resolved the first time and never let go. If that happens at
>   app startup or in a background thread where there’s no current
>   request, you’ll see this exception. You may need to adjust some
>   component lifetime scopes. Again, it’s really good to know how
>   dependency lifetime scopes work in general.